# Passing sonar.leak.period to sonar maven runner

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Assume we have a maven project with several versions released: 1.0, 1.1.

We started work on version 1.2, changed it in pom.xml, run sonar as usual. but in few days we decided to change version 1.2 to 2.0.

And now, sonar default leak period is started from 1.2 version. But, we'd like the leak period will be version 1.1.

I try to tune sonar.leak.period with maven command line parameter:

```
$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.leak.period=1.1 -e
```

But, I still see issues started from 1.2 in leak period statistics

Is there any option to set up sonar.leak.period from maven command line? How to debug it?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-core/src/main/java/org/sonar/core/config/CorePropertyDefinitions.java) (lines 36-43). Maybe 1.1 is an invalid value?

Comment: @JeroenHeier It looks like sonar.leak.period is not passed from command line. I tried it with date and still no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check version 1.1 is know in the Activity page of your project (you can filter Version event)
- change the leak setting to 1.1 at the project level, in the project General Settings